how to get signed url from non public bucket in google cloud storage?
currently i have cloud function to get signed url, I place the service account json in my google secret manager, and access it trough my code. I've test the function in post man, using identity token that i generated from cloud console and work perfectly, it return the signed url.
but the problem is, since the identity token has expired time, I confused how to integrate with my flutter project.
my question is :

best practice to get signed url to flutter project
should i make my bucket public? currently it has non-public because i store a important document to it

bellow is my code in my function, using python 3.10 :
import json
import functions_framework
from google.cloud import storage, secretmanager
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from flask import request, jsonify

@functions_framework.http
def generate_signed_url(request):
    try:
        # CORS preflight handling
        if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
            headers = {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization'
            }
            return ('', 204, headers)

        # Validate request method
        if request.method != 'POST':
            return jsonify({'error': 'Method not allowed'}), 405

        # Parse request JSON
        request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
        if not request_json:
            return jsonify({'error': 'Invalid JSON'}), 400

        # Extract required parameters
        bucket_name = 'my-good-bucket'
        file_name = request_json.get('fileName')
        expires_in = int(request_json.get('expiresIn', 15))

        if not file_name:
            return jsonify({'error': 'File name is required'}), 400

        # Retrieve the service account key from Secret Manager
        secret_name = "my-good-key" 
        project_id = "mygoodproject"  
        secret_manager_client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
        secret_path = f"projects/{project_id}/secrets/{secret_name}/versions/latest"

        secret_response = secret_manager_client.access_secret_version(request={"name": secret_path})
        service_account_key = secret_response.payload.data.decode("UTF-8")

        # Load credentials from the service account key
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(json.loads(service_account_key))
        storage_client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials)

        # Get bucket and blob
        bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
        blob = bucket.blob(file_name)

        # Generate signed URL
        signed_url = blob.generate_signed_url(
            version='v4',
            expiration=expires_in * 60,
            method='GET' 
        )

        return jsonify({
            'url': signed_url,
            'expires_in': expires_in * 60,
            'bucket': bucket_name,
            'file_name': file_name
        }), 200

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error generating signed URL: {e}")
        return jsonify({
            'error': 'Internal server error',
            'details': str(e)
        }), 500```


Your question is unclear. Can you not have your Flutter app invoke the Cloud Function and return the Signed URL? The purpose of Signed URLs is to provide access to users|software to objects in a bucket without granting the users more permanent permissions so you should not make the bucket public for the use as you've described it.
